# MySQL. Need to count number of posts in ~9000 categories

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, count

I'm making a sitemap. I have a table, which connects posts with categories (2 columns: categoryId, postId). There are nearly 9000 categories in total, and I want to count number of posts in each category to predict number of pages in pagination. I tried to do 9000 COUNT(*)'s for each category, but that is too slow (2 hours, actually). What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: I want to get number of posts in a category with specified id. Sorry, I forgot to add this important part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do a SELECT COUNT and GROUP it by your categoryid like this :

```
SELECT C, COUNT(*) FROM yourtable GROUP BY categoryId as C
```

If you want only for a specific category, try to use `WHERE categoryID = ?` 
before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: I actually want to take number of posts in a specific category, not all of them. But yes, this query is nice and it works really fast.

Comment: This query worked without categoryId. But without categoryId, it is actually useless.

Comment: You just have to use WHERE categoryid=? like i said in my edited post.

Comment: This query was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the GROUP BY function

```
SELECT C, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY categoryId as C
```

Comment: you are probably missing `as`: `GROUP BY categoryId **as** C`

Comment: I actually want to take number of posts in a specific category, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can count it and group it by CategoryID simple as that

```
select Count(postid) as NumberOfPosts, categoryid from your_table group by categoryid
```

and that is simple as that.

Best solution for you is to create table where you will hold real statistic and increase it when post is created or decrease it when post is deleted.

**NEW**
if you want for certain category then just add to query where `categoryid=?`

so your query should look like

```
select Count(postid) as NumberOfPosts from your_table where categoryid=?
```

or if you want to do search for more than one category than just do this

```
select Count(postid) as NumberOfPosts, categoryid from your_table where categoryid in (1,2,3,4)
group by categoryid
```

Comment: I actually want to take number of posts in a specific category, not all of them.

Comment: The "best solution" does not look best to me. I dont want to put s**t into my DB.

Comment: But I'm speaking about performance, its easier to select records from table where you have 9000 records instead to count number of records and group it by category from table where you  have more than one million records, and do this every time when someone opens your sitemap???